# How do I save a file in AI so that I can enlarge it in Photoshop without pixelation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, pixelation

I'm very inexperienced with Illustrator as I have always primarily used Photoshop. I have a eps file which I bought and have made changes to (ie deleting the bits I don't want). At this point I usually export it as a png file, open it in Photoshop and add the text or images I want. Frankly it's easier than figuring out how to do it in Illustrator.

Ordinarily at this point I can increase the file in Photoshop and use it as either a poster or flyer.  But the file I'm working on atm is very small and although there is no pixelation in AI, it's horrendous in Photoshop. I don't know how to save it in AI in a larger size so I don't have this problem in Photoshop.

Any advice/help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: D Save it as AI. As in do not export. PS: the time you took to write this question would have been enough to learn how to do text and add images in AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the Illustrator document in Photoshop as a smart object. You will be able to scale the smart object as much as you like and you can double-click on the smart object layer in Photoshop to open it up in Illustrator and make changes, which will update the layer in Photoshop.

- [**Photoshop / Work with Smart Objects**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html)

Using the *File → Place Linked...* command will create a smart object that is directly linked to the file you place, so any changes you make in the original Illustrator document will update in your Photoshop document.

Or you can simply copy and paste directly from an Illustrator document if that is easier. That will create an *embedded* smart object, which will make the smart object a part of your Photoshop document not linked to the original Illustrator document.